# Virtualbox on Windows host with bridged network adapter over wifi sometimes start, sometimes not start a VM Centos 7, why?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I need internet in VM to download stuffs easily.
I need multiple VMs at once for learning kubernetes.
Thus I chose bridged adapter(same happens with NATTed adapter though).
How do I debug this issue at the very least?

Comment: two links to help you understand that Wifi is not Ethernet especially when bridging: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header , https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged (it's not about promiscuous, it's about 2 vs 3 vs 4 MAC addresses).